# How to supply hiveconf variable from hive oozie action

Tags: oozie

I want to supply variable as `hiveconf` namespace from my hive-oozie action, how to do that?

```html
<action name="setupAct">
  <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
    <job-tracker>maprfs:///</job-tracker>
    <name-node>maprfs:///</name-node>
    <script>
      XYZ.hql
    </script>
    <!--how to add variable to hiveconf-->
    <param>DB_NAME=test</param>
  </hive>
  <ok to="ok" />
  <error to="error" />
</action>
```

The values inside `param` element are supplied as `--hivevar` namespace to hive.

Below is application log, the param element gets added as hivevar:

> ```
> ------------------------
>   DB_NAME=test
> ------------------------
> Hive command arguments :
>       --hivevar
>         DB_NAME=test
>         -f
>          test.hql
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `hiveconf` in Oozie, Use the **configuration** element.

```
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
    <job-tracker>maprfs:///</job-tracker>
    <name-node>maprfs:///</name-node>
    <script>
      XYZ.hql
    </script>
    <!--how to add variable to hiveconf-->
    <configuration>
       <property>
          <name>hive.default.fileformat</name>
          <value>Parquet</value>
       </property>
    </configuration>
    <param>DB_NAME=test</param>
  </hive>
```